# Debugging Ruby on Rails app 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection, irb

I have been using Ruby debugger and want to be able to get stack dumps from irb. How can I get  garbage collection dumps?
Also what patch should I use to be able to tweak the garbage collector a bit?

Comment: just a thought, but if you don't already know the answers to both these questions, you probably shouldn't be tweaking the GC at all

Comment: I don`t know anything about Ruby. I just got dropped into a huge Ruby project. I could do it in Java. Yes though, if you knew the ugly thing I wanted to do with the GC you would jump through the computer to slap me up.

Comment: what's your real goal, here, finding a memory leak?

Comment: Is it a Rails app? You mention Rails in the title but not in the body of the question or the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby you can re-open classes at any point and redefine them if you want. So you could re-open the GC class and add dumps or redefine any methods you want. You also create aliases of existing methods so that you could call them again later. For example. if you had a class `Foo` with a method `bar` that you wanted to add some functionality to, you could do something like:

```
class Foo
  alias :original_bar :bar
  def bar
    # do something new
    original_bar
  end
end
```

So you take the original `bar` method and alias it to `original_bar`, then re-open `bar` and insert your custom code, then reference the original `bar` method again. BEHOLD THE POWER OF RUBY!